# How to draw a clock animation by moving the 2nd hand line (Minutes)

Tags: python, animation, clock, turtle-graphics

Recently, I figured out on python how to make a moving line.

**What I want to do now is know how to do a clock animation with a moving 2nd hand (Minutes) and without the hour hand.**

**My current stage of the moving line animation:**
[image: Current state]

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[image: End result]

**since they're screenshots they don't show them moving**

*my code*

```
import turtle
import time
turtle.hideturtle()

def draw_line(x,y,heading,length,color):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.setheading(heading)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.fd(length)

turtle.tracer(0,0)
for heading in range(0,-360*100,-6):
    turtle.clear()
    draw_line(0,0,heading,200,'blue')
    turtle.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

it'd help also if someone provided how to draw the clock

Comment: You'll need to draw the clock then the hand each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking but I'm assuming it's two things: first, how to add another moving line; second, how to set the angles of these lines to match the actual (local) time.  I've reworked your code below to do both these things, and threw in an hour hand as well as the cost is low.  Something to consider:

You don't want to do this with a *single* turtle--you want *at least two*.  Otherwise, when you call `clear()`, you lose *everything*, including the dial, and have to redraw it.  You can work around this by either using `undo()`, or, more simply, have one turtle whose drawings are permanent (the dial) and another whose drawings are cleared on every tick (the hands).

Other changes below include: tossing `time.sleep()` in favor of turtle's own `ontimer()` event; switching from turtle's *function-based* API to its *object-oriented* one so we can manage two turtles.  And I switched turtle into ***Logo*** mode which puts zero degrees at the top of the screen, and makes angles for graphics be *clockwise* instead of *counter-clockwise* (which is useful if you're implementing a clock!)

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D
from time import localtime

CENTER = Vec2D(0, 0)

def draw_line(position, heading, length, color):
    hands.up()
    hands.goto(position)
    hands.down()
    hands.setheading(heading)
    hands.color(color)
    hands.forward(length)

def tick():
    time = localtime()

    second_heading = time.tm_sec * 6
    minute_heading = time.tm_min * 6 + second_heading / 60
    hour_heading = time.tm_hour % 12 * 30 + minute_heading / 12

    hands.clear()

    draw_line(CENTER, second_heading, 300, 'red')
    draw_line(CENTER, minute_heading, 200, 'blue')
    draw_line(CENTER, hour_heading, 100, 'green')

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)

screen = Screen()
screen.mode("logo")  # 0 degrees at top, clockwise angles!
screen.tracer(False)  # force manual screen updates

# What this turtle draws is "permanent"
dial = Turtle(visible=False)
dial.penup()
dial.dot()
dial.setx(330)  # remember mode is "logo"
dial.pendown()
dial.circle(330)

# What this turtle draws has to be redrawn on every tick
hands = Turtle(visible=False)

tick()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]